# ubuntu-mate 17.10 : keyboard shortcuts, definition file?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate

I asked this question in the mate user forum but have received no reply so I bring it here.

I run some ubuntu-mate VMs and so want to copy pieces of the configuration between VMs.

For most applications I have found settings in the ~/.config directory and its siblings, but I cannot find where the keyboard shortcuts are kept.

Is there a text file? Or perhaps an export/import facility?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can list all settings with `dconf` (from `dconf-cli` package) with

  ```
  dconf dump /
  ```

and search for keyboard shortcuts here.

- You can restore this settings with this example (change with your settings):

  ```
  dconf load / << EOF 
  [org/mate/terminal/keybindings]
  help='disabled'

  EOF
  ```

Comment: Thank you N0rbert.

If I go 

   $ dconf dump / > ddump.out 

and then examine ddump.out, I see that 'keybinding' appears under various headings and that there is nothing obvious to link these headings other than the 'keybindings' keyword. 

The file does not give all keys listed under the shortcuts dialog and references applications that I may not want to install to the target system. 

So I'm confused. I want to import only shortcuts. So, for example $ dconf load \ [*keybinding*].

Comment: I think that manual editing will be really needed. I did so for resetting only needed settings.

Comment: Thank you, yes. N0rbert. 
I found it easier for me to copy the interesting elements from the dump file into an input file and then redirect. "dconf load / < dconf.in"